# Как правильно запустить тесты для Gitlab CI

Tags: python, c++, gitlab-ci

Есть сервер - собирается на гитлабе. На питоне написал юнит-тесты, которые эмулируют клиента и тестируют сервер после сборки. Использую протобуф. Но когда сборщик переходит на стадию тестов - он не видит протобуфа. Пробовал его устанавливать - ошибка

> E: Unable to locate package libprotobuf-dev E: Unable to locate
> package protobuf-compile

Как на стадии тестов заставить работать протобуф?

```
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - apt-get -y install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
  script:
    - ./scripts/build_pb.sh
    - mkdir build && cd build
    - cmake ..
    - cmake --build .
    - ctest --extra-verbose
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/bin/release/server    

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - build/bin/release/server # запуск сервера
    - src/py_tests/server_tests.py # запуск тестов
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как на стадии тестов заставить работать протобуф?

**Решение**: вынести `before_script` в темплейт при помощи якорей или джоб-темплейтов:

```yaml
.protobuf:
  before_script:
    - apt-get -y install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler

build:
  extends: .protobuf
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./scripts/build_pb.sh
    - mkdir build && cd build
    - cmake ..
    - cmake --build .
    - ctest --extra-verbose
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/bin/release/server    

test:
  extends: .protobuf
  stage: test
  script:
    - build/bin/release/server # запуск сервера
    - src/py_tests/server_tests.py # запуск тестов
```

Подробная документация по якорям gitlab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors